# Chillling a bolt to remove it

Tags: repair

Years ago I had a stuck bolt that would not budge. I applied electronic component chiller, and then some creeping penetrant, and bolt came out. I thought I was a genius, until somebody pointed out there is a penetrant lube out there with a chilling component that combines both of the techniques I described. I don't remember the product name, but it worked very well when I had it. Does anyone know what the name of the product is?

Comment: Sounds like a weak product. What if you want to lube something you don't want to chill, chill something you don't want to lube, or lube early and let soak in? What if you want to use a better penetrating oil than that one?  But product recommendations are off topic for essentially all of StackExchange, so this is the wrong forum...

Comment: https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/crc-freeze-off-super-penetrant-115-wt-oz-05002/7080144-P

Comment: https://www.fastenal.com/products/details/0607066

Comment: Try this website, http://www.google.com - it is amazing at bubbling search results with a selection of keywords right to the top. Try "pentrat(e|ing|ion)" "lube|oil" and "freeze|cool|chill|reduce|cold"  :) I recommend turning on safe browsing with those words!!! Also, while cold does change matters shape, most people use heat and shock/vibration (vs cold), to break stubborn bolts/nuts free. They usually do this after or with a few treatments of penetration oil like liquid wrench.  Be careful with those search terms!

Comment: 1) https://www.amazon.com/DuPont-Deep-Freeze-Penetrating-11-Ounce/dp/B00JM371SK
2) http://www.finishlineusa.com/products/specialty-products/chill-zone